# How do I open a game compiled for WebGL in Unity in Blazor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, blazor, blazor-server-side, unity-webgl

I have created a Blazor Server project. In it, I wanted to put my WebGL game created in Unity3d on a separate page. In the end, after doing everything according to the example, I still can't get it to work. Although, I think, all things considered, but I see that the code markup index.html from WebGL game is different from other examples and there I haven't found a line of code:

```
unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "unity/WebGL/Build/WebGL.loader.js", { onProgress: UnityProgress });
```

I think I hooked it up right:

```
<script src="~/unity/WebGL/Build/WebGL.loader.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/unity/WebGL/Build/WebGL.framework.js.gz"></script>*@
<script src="~/unity/WebGL/run.js"></script>
```

I believe I wrote the mime type correctly:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

provider.Mappings.Remove(".data.gz");
provider.Mappings[".data.gz"] = "application/octet-stream";
provider.Mappings.Remove(".wasm.gz");
provider.Mappings[".wasm.gz"] = "application/wasm";
provider.Mappings.Remove(".js.gz");
provider.Mappings[".js.gz"] = "application/javascript";
provider.Mappings.Remove(".symbols.json.gz");
provider.Mappings[".symbols.json.gz"] = "application/octet-stream";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "unity", "WebGL", "Build")),
    RequestPath = "/Build",
    ContentTypeProvider = provider 
});
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

The error in the JavaScript console reads:

> UnityLoader is not defined

If interested, here is my entire project:

https://github.com/EgorPavlovich/FPS.Servers.Test

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Egor, I'm unable to figure out what you meant by the sentence, "Although, I think, all things considered, but I see that the code markup index.html from WebGL game is different from other examples and there I haven't found a line of code."  Can you elaborate on this point some more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the index.html file from the game build

Comment: Could you elaborate how you used the index.html from the game build in blazor?  Afterall, blazor is a SPA application